# How do I Implement "Continuous with Minimum or Nothing" Variables in DocPlex?

Tags: python, optimization, cplex, nonlinear-optimization, docplex

I have a 5-20 variables in my problems, and generally for 3-6 the allowable solution space is either continuous down to a minimum value or exactly zero.  For example, in one problem the first variable (x0) can be either be between 250-1000 or it can be 0.

The minimization is on a complex, piecewise-linear/non-linear function f(x0,...,xn).

Is this possible to do in a single Docplex model/minimize call?  If so, does Docplex behave well with these sort of holes in the solution space?

Comment: This is called a semicontinuous variable. See the documentation for exact syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This concept is called a "semi-continuous" or "semi-integer" variable. Looking at the documentation you will find functions `semicontinuous_var`, `semicontinuous_var_dict`, ... in the `Model` class. These functions will create variables with the properties you asked for:

```
x0 = model.semicontinuous_var(250, 1000, "x0")
```

Note that using a semi-continuous variable will implicitly turn your model into a MIP.

Comment: Looks like the solution, Thanks.  Two questions.  Does Semi-Continuous assume 0 as the odd point?   My problem is already an MIQP would adding this change it to a different type?

Comment: yes, 0 is always the singular value for semi-continuous variables. Note that their lower bound must be strictly positive.

Comment: As your problem is already Mixed Integer (from piecewise-linear functions) its type should not change.